# Appcelerator: Show push messages in the Notification Center when the app is in the foreground (open)

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

If the iOS app is open and a push message arrives, the push message does not appear in the NotificationCenter. I can process the content in the opened app. But the typical banner doesn't come.

Does anyone have a solution for Appcelerator (iOS)?

Or do I know whether the app was opened via a push message?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an alert or something else yourself while the app is running in foreground. The notification will only appear when it is in background.

Comment: It's a shame, I was afraid.